# Image POST request error in flask-nginx-uwsgi

Tags: nginx, flask, uwsgi

Doing nginx & uwsgi with flask

```
@app.route('/upload/', defaults={'values': None}, methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/upload/<values>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload(values):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        fs = request.files.get('h-img')
        if fs:
            img = cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer(fs.read(), np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
            #if not color is passed
            if not values:
                img  = cv2.imencode('.jpg', img)[1].tobytes()
                stringData = base64.b64encode(img).decode('utf-8')

                return stringData

            else:
                #processing

                return stringData
        else:
            return 'No data found'
    
    return 'POST is required'
```

My nginx.conf

```
server {
    client_max_body_size 100m;
    listen 5000;
    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass flask:8080;
    }

}
```

Here when I am calling "localhost:5000" then it works fine but when requesting the POST request "localhost:5000/upload/12345" it's throwing an error.

**ERROR:**
22#22: *4 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 123.45.0.1, server: , request: "POST /upload/12345 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://123.45.0.3:8080", host: "localhost:5000", referrer: "localhost:5000"

Comment: NGINX is complaining that the Python app didn’t send any response headers, i.e. malformed response. So the app is probably throwing an error.

Comment: @palindromeotter33 But why it's complaining about it? I am trying this with docker though. Btw when I am using "localhost:5000/upload/" without further value then it works fine but when requesting as localhost:5000/upload/<value> it's throwing the error.